# Una pagina con varios divs y un formulario en cada uno

Tags: javascript, html, formularios

Estoy haciendo una página con elementos que se pueden comentar:

```
element_1 (id_1)  --->escribe tu comentario ---> OnClick abre div con un formulario
element_2 (id_2)  --->escribe tu comentario ---> OnClick abre div con el mismo formulario
element_3 (id_3)  --->escribe tu comentario ---> OnClick abre div con el mismo formulario
etc.
```

Como cualquier sitio con comentarios, al hacer click, via AJAX, se abre el formulario correspondiente (que es siempre el mismo), con un textarea para escribir tu comentario. Cada formulario incluye un captcha.

**Formulario**

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="<?php echo $post_id; ?>" class="comment">
   <textarea name="comment_post" maxlength=400 id="comment_post"></textarea><br />

   Enter code...
   <img src="grafica/img.php?rand=<?php echo rand(); ?>" id='captchaimg' ><br>
   <input id="6_letters_code" name="6_letters_code" type="text"><br>
   <span style="margin-left:105px;position: relative;top: -15px;"><small>Can't read the image? click <a href='javascript: refreshCaptcha();'>here</a> to refresh</small></span><br/>
   <input type="button" class="submit" value=" Submit Comment " />
</form>
```

**Enviar comentario**

```
$(function() {
$(".submit").click(function() {
var comment_post = $("#comment_post").val();
var captcha = $("#6_letters_code").val();
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
... se envia el formulario ...
```

**Refrescar captcha**

```
function refreshCaptcha()
{
    var img = document.images['captchaimg'];
    img.src = img.src.substring(0,img.src.lastIndexOf("?"))+"?rand="+Math.random()*1000;
}
```

Cuando abrimos un div funciona (enviar y captcha), pero **cuando abrimos un segundo div**, el envío del formulario y `refreshCaptcha()` **dejan de funcionar**.

Sospecho que esto sucede por meter varios formularios en divs sin refrescar página. Si alguien sabe cómo resolverlo, se lo agradecería.

Comment: aparece algo en la consola?

Comment: Imagino que cada formulario tiene ids diferentes así como los ids de sus elementos. ¿Podrías situar el código resumido de las operaciones que haces cuando se hace `submit` del formulario y se actualizan los `captchas`?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que falta algo de información.

¿Los formularios son estáticos?, es decir, ¿Siempre están el la página o los estas cargando con AJAX? ¿O como haces para que el formulario que "que es siempre el mismo" pase al segundo div?

Te pregunto esto porque si estas trayendo el formulario con AJAX o si lo estas moviendo de su lugar es propale que el script no sepa que existe, porque javaScript se ejecuta una sola vez, así que tendrías que volver a crear el evento "$(".submit").click(function(){...})" en el success del AJAX o mejor aún, puedes crear una función y mandarla a llamar en el success, así:

```
(function($){
function btnSubmit(){
    $('.submit').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '...',
            success: function(result){
                btnSubmit();
            }
        });
    });
}}(jQuery));
```